# How fast is a true vacuum bubble going to expand?

Tags: space-expansion, vacuum

If a true vacuum bubble will occur in our universe, how fast is it going to expand?

Comment: The speed of light

Comment: @MichaelBrown is going to expand at our value of speed of light (300.000 km/s) because is the top speed for information to travel?

Comment: @MichaelBrown: It's generally said that a phase change would propagate at the speed of light, but is this just a general principle that it would propagate *as fast as it can* or is there a calculation to back up the claim?

Comment: @JohnRennie that's what im tryng to understand

Comment: @JohnRennie It's general for the false vacuum case. The calculations are found in the old papers by Coleman. Basically you have an $O(4)$ invariant bubble solution in Euclidean space which you Wick rotate back to Minkowski spacetime to get a hyperboloid which asymptotes to the light cone. So not really $c$, but exponentially close to it for macroscopic times. In the finite temperature case (like a first order phase transition in the early universe) the plasma causes friction which slows down the bubble wall, possibly even to subsonic velocities (see the electroweak phase transition literature)

Comment: Early false vacuum papers [Coleman. Phys.Rev. D15 (1977) 2929-2936](http://inspirehep.net/record/118681)
[Coleman, De Luccia. Phys.Rev. D21 3305-3315](http://prd.aps.org/abstract/PRD/v21/i12/p3305_1)
Early electroweak bubble dynamics paper [Moore, G., & Prokopec, T. (1995). Phys.Rev. D52(12) 7182–7204.](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9506475)